# JSON AngularJS multiple objects

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm just curious as in how to access any field in this JSON call as it has multiple objects and is very confusing as it is my first time dealing with this. Here is the link to the JSON:
http://api.wunderground.com/api/5ad0204df4bdbeff/forecast/q/Australia/Sydney.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK

My code uses AngularJS to call the JSON and then store it. A bound value then access it by looping through.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>

    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.25"></script>
    <script >

    var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
   $http.jsonp('http://api.wunderground.com/api/5ad0204df4bdbeff/forecast/q/Australia/Sydney.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data){
     console.log(data);
     $scope.weatherData=data;
  })
});
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="weather in weatherData">
            {{weather.celsius}}
        </li>
    </ul>   
  </body>

</html>
```

Essentially I want to access the "simpleforecast" object and then access the temperature area. How would I go about this?

Comment: what do you receive in console.log(data); ?

Comment: Object { response: Object, forecast: Object } but you can expand it further

Comment: so you can just go through the properties in seceived object and finally see in on the view. Like weatherData.forecast.somePropertyHere

Comment: Essentially you can view all the way through to that but do i put that in the {{}} bound value area?

Comment: you can use weatherData.forecast.forecast.simpleforecast for accessing "simpleforecast" object

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I made a fiddle for you to demonstrate the usage with ng-repeat. Here is **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cemozer/fwewcfqL/1/)**

It must be like that:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="forecast in weatherData.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday">
        <br/>date: {{forecast.date.pretty}} 
        <br/>high: {{forecast.high.celsius}},  
        <br/>low: {{forecast.low.celsius}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

I recommend to use some JSON viewer/formatter tool to find the data you want from a complex JSON. Actually I found it using **[that](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)** tool.

To get today's low and high temperatures

```
data.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[0].high.celsius

data.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[0].low.celsius
```

Also service gives 4 days of weather, if you want them change index of forecast day. 0 is today, 1 is tomorrow and so on.

Comment: Corrected typo in celsius. Also added a working fiddle to demonstrate the usage with ng-repeat.

Comment: ahh ok i know what i was doing wrong when testing it i was putting weatherData.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday in the {{}}

Answer (score 0):

```
<li ng-repeat="weather in weatherData.forecast.forecast.simpleforecast">
   {{weather.forecastday[0].high.celsius}}
   {{weather.forecastday[0].low.celsius}}
</li>
```

Comment: try {{weather.forecastday[0].high.celsius}}